# Javascript - Sort array after initial '-'

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, split

What is the cleanest method of sorting an array of string values using vanilla javascript.  I would like to sort alphabetically after each values opening '-'.  Example array...

```
array = [
    '1028341000-AJINOMOTO WINDSOR HAYWARD-HAYWARD',
    '1018551000-ZEBRA PIERRE',
    '1023221000-NEVERENDER WORMHOLE CHEYENNE-CHEYENNE'
]
```

So, correct order would be 1,3,2.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: is the hyphen always at the same position?

Comment: @gurvinder372 There are other `-` in the string after the first

Comment: @NinaScholz Not always at the same position but always want the sort to happen after the first dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using split and localeCompare:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.split("-")[1].localeCompare(b.split("-")[1]);
});
```

Will split the string at the first `-` and then grab everything after as a string. Compares both and does the normal sort.

Comment: try sorting this array with your solution: `['1028341000-AJINOMOTO WINDSOR HAYWARD-HAYWARD', '1028341000-AJINOMOTO WINDSOR HAYWARD-APPLES`]`

Comment: When you ignore the data after the last `-`, you return incorrect results.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen This is true. OP needs to correct his choice of correct answer.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Still does not work with your input. That will just leave off the `HAYWARD` and `APPLES` part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
array.sort( (a, b) => a.substr(a.indexOf('-')).localeCompare(b.substr(b.indexOf('-'))) );
```

```js
var array = [
    '1028341000-AJINOMOTO WINDSOR HAYWARD-HAYWARD',
    '1018551000-ZEBRA PIERRE',
    '1023221000-NEVERENDER WORMHOLE CHEYENNE-CHEYENNE'
];

array.sort( (a, b) => a.substr(a.indexOf('-')).localeCompare(b.substr(b.indexOf('-'))) );

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the strings and sort by string.

```js
var array = ['1028341000-AJINOMOTO WINDSOR HAYWARD-HAYWARD', '1018551000-ZEBRA PIERRE', '1023221000-NEVERENDER WORMHOLE CHEYENNE-CHEYENNE'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getS(s) { return s.slice(1 + s.indexOf('-')); }

    var aa = getS(a),
        bb = getS(b);

    return aa > bb || -(aa < bb);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
array.sort( function(a,b){
   var astr = a.substring(a.indexOf("-")+1);
   var bstr = b.substring(b.indexOf("-")+1);
   return astr.localeCompare(bstr);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var array = [
    '1028341000-AJINOMOTO WINDSOR HAYWARD-HAYWARD',
    '1018551000-ZEBRA PIERRE',
    '1023221000-NEVERENDER WORMHOLE CHEYENNE-CHEYENNE'
];
array.sort( function(a,b){
   var astr = a.substring(a.indexOf("-")+1);
   var bstr = b.substring(b.indexOf("-")+1);
   return astr.localeCompare(bstr);
});
console.log(array);
```